# Nested if and while adding to arraylist not working as intended

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I have a problem with my if and while statement in this method. The desired function is to choose a number between the range of 1 to 5, and add an object to arraylist. There's a field in the class called numberOfShips that is used in the while loop, which decides the max number of objects in the array. The count variable should keep track of when the limit is reached.

However, that's not what happens. I pick e.g. 1, and it adds choice 1 numberOfShips times. Then it says the fleet is full, because that's the limit. I can't seem to figure out the what the problem is, since I've tried several variations with the if statements, and I've also tried out a do while, which did not work.

```
public ArrayList<Ship> createFleet(int choice) {
        ArrayList<Ship> fleet = new ArrayList<Ship>();
        int count = 0;
        if(choice > 1 && choice < 5) {
            while ((count < numberOfShips)) {
                if (choice == 1) {
                    Ship ac = new Ship("Aircraft carrier", 5, false);
                    fleet.add(ac);
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Aircraft carrier has been added to fleet.");
                } else if (choice == 2) {
                    Ship bs = new Ship("Battleship", 4, false);
                    fleet.add(bs);
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Battleship has been added to fleet.");
                } else if (choice == 3) {
                    Ship sm = new Ship("Submarine", 3, false);
                    fleet.add(sm);
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Submarine has been added to fleet.");
                } else if (choice == 4) {
                    Ship ds = new Ship("Destroyer", 3, false);
                    fleet.add(ds);
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Destroyer has been added to fleet.");
                } else {
                    Ship sp = new Ship("Patrol Boat", 2, false);
                    fleet.add(sp);
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Patrol boat has been added to fleet.");
                }
            } //while
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not an option.");
        }
        System.out.println("Fleet contains maximum ships.\nYour fleet is:");
        for (int i = 0; i < fleet.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(fleet.get(i));
        }
        start();
        return fleet;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need the while, you need to do the following

```
if(count < numberOfShips && choice > 0 && choice < 5) {
   // Check which ship
}
```

Also, the variable count should be outside the method, thus:

```
public class Test { 
   private int numberOfShips = 400;
   private int count;

   public ArrayList<Ship> createFleet(int choice) {
       ArrayList<Ship> fleet = new ArrayList<Shipe>();
       if(count < numberOfShips) {
         if(choice > 0 && choice < 5) {
            //appropriate ship..
         }
       } else {
          System.out.prinln("Capactity reached");
       }  
   }
}
```

The while in your code will continue until the capactiy is reched, with this it is not. 
While is a loop, if is a check to put it in simple words